# Adding exceptions during cut returns unwanted results

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file that is being generated (sort of an audit file) with who have accessed said file. Looks as follows:

[image]

I need to write an alarming system that enters said report and checks for all users. however bash for some reason interprets the "------" as an input.

```
for i in $(cut -c 8-13 report_file.csv)
do
if [[ $i -eq 'suser' ]] || [[ $i -eq '--------' ]] || [[ $i -eq 'login' ]] || $i -eq 'root']] 
then 
break
else 
echo "email text"+ $i | mailx -s "email subject" $EMAILS_LIST
done
```

the output for this is:

> ./script_name.sh: line 26: [[: --------: syntax error: operand
>   expected (error token is "-")

So as I understand it takes the exception "------" and still sees it as sort of input.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's bash? Bash prepends the word `bash` to its errors.

Answer (score 3):

`-eq` in [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (same in [extended test [[...]]](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html)) is an operator for integers. `'---------'` is not an integer. Use `=` to compare strings.

`... [[ "$i" = 'suser' ]] || [[ "$i" = '--------' ]] || [[ "$i" = 'login' ]] || [[ "$i" = 'root' ]]`

or simpler

`... [[ "$i" = 'suser' || "$i" = '--------' || "$i" = 'login' || "$i" = 'root' ]]`

or simpler:

```
case "$i" in 
suser|--------|login|root) ;; 
*) echo "email text"+ $i | mailx -s "email subject" $EMAILS_LIST; ;;
esac
```

Side note:
Reading lines from file using `for i in $(...)` is [bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). It's better to use `while read -r line; do .... done < <(cut -c 8-13 report_file.csv)` or `cut -c 8-13 report_file.csv | while read -r line; do ... done` see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).